# how to putting bean to css style button

Tags: java, css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i'm using primefaces 3.5 with jsf 2 , my page have coustom menu and it's css style sheets .

i have created just button to LogOut but i don't know how to put logout bean correctly with out crash the button style .

by bean is :

```
#{loginBean.doLogout}
```

HTML PAGE code :

```
    <body >

    <ui:composition template="/Templates/MasterTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
<div class="inside">
    <div class="trans">
        <div class="fix">
        <a class="logo" href=""></a>
        <div class="show">
        <ul class="menu">
        <li > <a href="">اتصل بنا</a></li>
        <li > <a href="">LogOut button</a></li>  <<<***** here i want to put the tage ******* 
        <li > <a href="">التقارير</a>
        <ul >
        <li><a href="#{request.contextPath}/secured/Report/Student/SpecificStudent.xhtml">تقرير عن طالب محدد</a></li>
        <li><a href="#{request.contextPath}/secured/Report/Student/SpecificClass.xhtml">تقرير عن فصل محدد</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li > <a href="http://sams-app.com/almnzm2-0/">الرئيسية</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="both">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />


<p:meterGaugeChart id="sample" value="#{chartBean.meterGaugeModel}" style="width:400px;height:250px" title="مستوى الحضور أمس لجميع الطلاب" label="نسبة الحضور/الطلاب"/>  



<p:meterGaugeChart id="custom" value="#{chartBean.meterGaugeModel}" showTickLabels="true" labelHeightAdjust="110" intervalOuterRadius="130"   
                               seriesColors="66cc66, 93b75f, E7E658, cc6666" style="width:400px;height:250px" title="Custom Options" label="km/h"/>  


        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

note : my bean is working fine with :

```
            <h:commandLink action="#{loginBean.doLogout}" value="Logout"/>
```

but i want to create it with the same above button style with the css .

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<h:commandButton/>` or add a css style to your `<h:commandLink/>` to look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<h:commandButton 
    onclick="window.location.assign('#{request.contextPath}#{loginBean.doLogout}');return false;" />
```